# Помощь со Spring Security/MVC

Tags: java, spring, безопасность, entity

Пытаюсь разбираться со спрингом постепенно создавая пет проект. 
У меня есть 2 Entity: User, Role. Они связаны ManyToMany.

Вот кусок связи из класса User:

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Добавляю в проект Spring Security. Когда тестировал с

```
@Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
             User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
```

и авторизовался по этим данным, то все окай, Когда по гайдам реализовал свой UserDetailsService

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    IUserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepo.getByLogin(username);
    }
}
```

И в конфиге Spring Security заменил на него, то при попытке авторизоваться имею вот такую ошибку:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.pet.model.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Сессия закрывается и не читает данные ролей пользователей. 
Кто может посоветовать как решить траблу? Роли лежат в Бд, класс Role - Entity.
Что пробовал:
1. Менять LAZY на EAGER - ошибка "No message available";
2. Пробовал проставть над сервисами @Transactional. - толку ноль.

В проекте Spring Data JPA.
Пробовал добавить SQL запросом юзера, потом роль и связать их. После этого в тесте хотел получить его роль (user.getRoles() который возвращает сет) имею всегда ошибку.

Comment: Сначала надо открыть сессию, а потом вытаскивают обьекты

Comment: Проблема решилась иным способом. Пришлось создать отдельный репозиторий для ролей и подгружать роли из базы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась иным способом. Пришлось создать отдельный репозиторий для ролей и подгружать роли из базы.